# Name and dashes in Biblatex

Tags: biblatex

Please, consider this code:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{ kuhn:1980,
  author         = "Thomas Kuhn",
  title          = "Logica della scoperta o psicologia della ricerca?",
  crossref   = "lakatos:1980",
  pages      = "69-93",
}
@book{ kuhn:1982,
  author         = "Thomas Kuhn",
  title          = "La struttura delle rivoluzioni scientifiche",
  publisher      = "Einaudi",
  location       = "Torino",
  year           = "1978",
}
@book{ kuhn:1985,
  author         = "Thomas Kuhn",
  title          = "La tensione essenziale",
  publisher      = "Einaudi",
  location       = "Torino",
  year           = "1985",
}
@collection{ lakatos:1980,
  title      = "Critica e crescita della conoscenza",
  editor     = "Imre Lakatos and Alan Musgrave",
  publisher      = "Feltrinelli",
  location       = "Milano",
  year           = "1980",
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,italian=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=philosophy-verbose,backend=biber,scauthors=true,%
classical=true,firstinits=true,commacit=true,volnumformat=strings,%
volumeformat=romansc,sorting=nyt,citepages=omit,indexing]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

IMHO, it's useless that the third occurrency appear with full name. The author is always the same (as the reader can easily understand), so, as in all other cases, it would be there the dash. Is there a way to correct this behavior to have everywhere the dashes after the first occurrency of the author's name? thanx

Comment: It does not happen with other styles that use dashes for repeated authors. So, you might consider this a bug in the `philosophy-verbose` style.

Comment: @Guido Stylistic choice, I'd say.

Comment: I don't know how to solve it, but what is causing the problem here is the crossref... As an "emergency solution" you could replace the crossref field by a note in the (hopely few) problematic cases.

Comment: I'm so sure it's an aware choice, for the reader understands very well the author's name even if there is only a dash...

Answer (score 2):

This is what I get from your example

[image]

The author's name is changed into a dash in every occurrence after the first. You may have outdated versions of the software.

This is the file list

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size11.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
inputenc.sty    2014/04/30 v1.2b Input encoding file
    utf8.def    2014/09/29 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   t1enc.dfu    2014/09/29 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ot1enc.dfu    2014/09/29 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  omsenc.dfu    2014/09/29 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   babel.sty    2014/09/25 3.9l The Babel package
 italian.ldf    2014/03/29 v1.3k Italian support from the babel system
etoolbox.sty    2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
csquotes.sty    2011/10/22 v5.1d context-sensitive quotations
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
csquotes.def    2011/10/22 v5.1d csquotes generic definitions
csquotes.cfg    
biblatex.sty    2014/06/25 v2.9a programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex2.sty    2014/06/25 v2.9a programmable bibliographies (biber) (PK/JW/AB
)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
  logreq.sty    2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
  logreq.def    2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  blx-dm.def
philosophy-verbose.dbx
biblatex-dm.cfg
blx-compat.def    2014/06/25 v2.9a biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex.def    
standard.bbx    2014/06/25 v2.9a biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
authortitle.bbx    2014/06/25 v2.9a biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
philosophy-standard.bbx    2014/03/28 v0.9f valbusa beta
philosophy-verbose.bbx    2014/03/28 v0.9f valbusa beta
verbose-trad2.cbx    2014/06/25 v2.9a biblatex citation style (PK/JW/AB)
philosophy-verbose.cbx    2014/03/28 v0.9f valbusa beta
biblatex.cfg    
 italian.lbx    2014/06/25 v2.9a biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
italian-philosophy.lbx    2014/03/28 v0.9f valbusa beta
    kuhn.bbl
 ***********
```

Comment: There are some bugs in philosophy(.verbose). Now all's working, at least for this matter. The package author/maintainer will correct and update his package in the next weeks (so he said)