# Replace dash with idem/eadem in verbose-trad1

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I'm currently using biblatex with the verbose-trad1 style.

Now, I saw in the bibliography that the author gets replaced by a dash when it is multiply referenced because he/she has more than one book:

[image]

(this is an example from [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/216079/name-and-dashes-in-biblatex/220544)).

Now, I was asked to replace the dashes with idem/eadem. Is it possible? The author of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11138) wrote

> With biblatex, the author can be replaced by a dash (or “idem”) in the bibliography

so I think it is possible, but.. How?

EDIT: I already knew that there was a solution for the problem (in fact I already linked the question marked as duplicate in the original text).

Now, since the author of the other question asks for a way to put idem/eadem for partial matches, and he already knew a way to put it for complete matches, I assumed that there was another way to put idem/eadem instead of dash in the bibliography already embedded in some style or requiring something else. I was asking for that style or something else...

Comment: The answer is there: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29401/124577

Comment: Since you know about the answer that is suggested as a duplicate, I think you want to achieve something different. Can you explain what exactly is different about your question. Is it only the style?

Comment: @moewe I added the reason why I thought that question was not a complete answer to mine. Summing up: the poster asked for a variation of what I wanted (idem/eadem not necessarily for partial matches), and since what I want was already knew by him maybe the answer is not the best in my case, so I was asking for another way (the poster's one or another) to do this, maybe just changing the style or modifying something else)

Comment: For future reference please keep in mind that it is better to provide an MWE in your question directly instead of linking to one, especially if - like in this case - your question is about `verbose-trad1`, but the code you link to uses the `philosophy-verbose` style. Such tiny differences matter.

Answer (score 2):

With the standard styles that offer dashes as well as most well-written custom styles that do (certainly `biblatex-philsophy`) it is enough to do

```
\renewcommand*{\bibnamedash}{\bibstring[\mkibid]{idem\thefield{gender}}}
```

Some styles don't define `\mkibid`, so we might need

```
\providecommand*{\mkibid}[1]{#1}
```

if the above alone throws errors (many styles that support the `dashed` option already define this command).

In order to get the gender of 'idem'/'eadem'/'eaedem'/'eidem' right, you need to fill the `gender` field in your `.bib` file

```
@book{kuhn:1982,
  author    = {Thomas Kuhn},
  gender    = {sm},
  title     = {La struttura delle rivoluzioni scientifiche},
  publisher = {Einaudi},
  location  = {Torino},
  year      = {1978},
}
```

Have a look at the `biblatex` documentation for a list of supported values for the field `gender`.

Comment: What about changing the style of idem entry, say to `{\sc Id./Ead./...}`? `\DefineBibliographyStrings{language}` `idem = {\textsc{Id}\adddot}` changes it globally and provides a generic small caps Id. if the gender is not specified. Is there a similar command for the rest of the abbreviations? One that may work in parallel with this one, possibly, and gets overrun when gender is unspecified?

Comment: @Mattia The downside of including formatting commands in bibstrings is that it can confuse the capitalisation feature. For that reason I usually try to avoid using formatting commands in translations. For other genders the strings are called `idemsm`, `idemsf`, `idemsn`, `idempm`, `idempf`, `idempn`, `idempp` (cf. also §4.9.2.16 Citations & the bit about the `gender` field in the `biblatex` manual)